# localstack start command is throwing exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, localstack

I tried to install **localstack** to test my lambda function, which uses **dynamodb**, **sqs** services.
To test this lambda function I installed **localstack** and followed the steps, which they gave in **Readme.md** file.
But when I tried to start localstack service by running **"localstack start"** command, it ends with below exception.
I have used **"pip install localstack"** command for installation

[localstack exception while running it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnOwo.png)

Exception:

```
sfanish@fanish-PC MINGW64 /c/Python27/Scripts 
$ localstack start 
$ localstack start 2017-12-27T14:37:50:INFO:localstack.services.install: 
Downloading and installing local Elasticsearch server. 
This may take some time. Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit. 
ERROR: 'mkdir -p C:\python27\lib\site-packages\localstack/infra': The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I am using windows10 64-bit machine, Python2.7. Any help will be great :)

Comment: Below is the exception i am getting.sfanish@fanish-PC MINGW64 /c/Python27/Scripts
$ localstack start  $ localstack start
2017-12-27T14:37:50:INFO:localstack.services.install: Downloading an                                     d installing local Elasticsearch server. This may take some time.
Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
ERROR: 'mkdir -p C:\python27\lib\site-packages\localstack/infra': Th                                     e syntax of the command is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that the path contains both '/' and '\'. Windows even with MINGW64 is not well supported by localstack.

Solutions:

- Try the last version of [localstack/localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack).
- Fix the issue in localstack code.
- Use a virtual environment (Virtual Box, Hyper-V, Docker) that support fully the GNU/Linux syntax.